# Instantiating a ListAdapter// Error using AsymmetricGridView

Tags: android

I am trying to use this [library](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView)

It says I should do as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
listView = (AsymmetricGridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

// Choose your own preferred column width
listView.setRequestedColumnWidth(Utils.dpToPx(this, 120));
final List<AsymmetricItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

// initialize your items array
adapter = new ListAdapter(this, listView, items);
AsymmetricGridViewAdapter asymmetricAdapter =
    new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<>(this, listView, adapter);
listView.setAdapter(asymmetricAdapter);
}
```

But When I try adapter = new ListAdapter();

It says that ListAdapter is abstract and thus cannot be instantiated...

I don't get this constructor ListAdapter(this, listView, items) since it's not there in android.widget.ListAdapter nor do I get any solutions to my problem...

Has anyone used this library as stated up there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) that you are trying to instantiate is a public interface, thus you can't instantiate it.

The `ListAdapter` mentioned in [the example code snippet from the library](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) in your case, is an unfortunate naming for a class that is intended to be implementing an adapter.

You should look into writing your own implementation of an adapter. For an example, the library you mentioned has a [DefaultListAdapter](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/felipecsl/asymmetricgridview/app/widget/DefaultListAdapter.java), you should look into it.

So that you will instantiate the custom adapter and use it.